# <f:view locale=""/> throws NullPointerException

Tags: jsf

I'm developing an web application using JSF and I need to make the web available in other languages. I haven't developed the app, I have to continue its development. In some views the following is used:

```
<f:view locale="#{nuevoProyectoBacking.locale}"/>
<f:loadBundle basename="com.company.resources.resdisenyo" var="rDisenyo"/>
```

So I've created a new JSF page and done the same:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">
        <f:event type="preRenderView"
                 listener="#{nuevoProyectoBacking.forwardIfIsNotAdmin}" />

        <f:view locale="#{nuevoProyectoBacking.locale}"/>
        <f:loadBundle basename="com.appglass.resources.resdisenyo" var="rDisenyo"/>

        <ui:define name="top">
            <ui:decorate template="/WEB-INF/templates/menuAdministrador.xhtml"></ui:decorate>
        </ui:define>
         etc
```

It only works if I remove f:view locale="#{nuevoProyectoBacking.locale}"

nuevoProyectoBacking.java

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class NuevoProyectoBacking implements Serializable{
definitions

/** Creates a new instance of NuevoProyectoBacking */
    public NuevoProyectoBacking()
    {
        many assignments
        locale = LocaleUtil.getIdioma(getCurrentUser().getIdioma());
     }

    public String getLocale() {
        return locale;
    }

    public void setLocale(String locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }

    public Usuarios getCurrentUser()
    {
        return (Usuarios) getSessionMap().get("currentUser");
    }
    public Map<String, Object> getSessionMap() {
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Map<String, Object> sessionMap = context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
        return sessionMap;
     }
}
```

LocaleUtil

```
public class LocaleUtil {


    public static String getIdioma(Integer idioma){

        if(idioma == 0){
            return "es_ES";
        } else if (idioma == 1) {
            return "en_US";
        } else if (idioma == 2) {
            return "it_IT";
        } else if (idioma == 3) {
            return "fr_FR";
        } else if (idioma == 4) {
            return "pt_PT";
        } else if (idioma == 5) {
            return "ru_RU";
        } else if (idioma == 6) {
            return "pl_PL";
        }else {
            return "es_ES";
        }

    }

}
```

Error

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager$ScopeManager$ViewScopeHandler.getFromScope(BeanManager.java:566)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager$ScopeManager.getFromScope(BeanManager.java:477)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.getBeanFromScope(BeanManager.java:240)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:255)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:116)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getBase(AstValue.java:151)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:200)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getObject(TagAttributeImpl.java:356)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getObject(TagAttributeImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:211)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:161)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.ViewMetadataImpl.createMetadataView(ViewMetadataImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:241)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I don't think the problem is in nuevoProyectoBacking as it is used by another JSF Page and it works well, language too. I have to remove that one and create a new one with a new look and feel.

Comment: What this `LocaleUtil.getIdioma(getCurrentUser().getIdioma());` does behind the scene is invisible but a locale is to be stored into a user's session. You can use a session scoped managed bean and initialize a locale in its `@PostConstruct` method (Avoid using a constructor for initialization tasks, since the object of the managed bean is not fully constructed until the constructor finishes its job in its entirely).

Comment: Which Mojarra version? Stack suggests that view scope isn't created yet at that point. Regardless, why a view scoped bean for this purpose instead of a session scoped bean? The logic shown so far is based on session scoped data, it wouldn't make sense to repeat it for every single view. By the way, you're indeed not supposed to perform initialization directly in bean constructor, you should use a `@PostConstruct` annotated method for that.

Comment: I've added more code to the post. I've also changed that constructor by @PostConstruct public void init() but I still have the same problem. Thank you! BalusC I'm using Mojarra 2.2.7 thnx!

Comment: BalusC I didn't write that bean, but I guess it is made like this because all data needed is based on view scoped except locale and current user which are session scope.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it but I don't know why xDDDD

This is my new JSF page

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

    <ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/templates/template.xhtml">
        <f:event type="preRenderView"
                 listener="#{nuevoProyectoBacking.forwardIfIsNotAdmin}" />

        <ui:define name="top">
            <ui:decorate template="/WEB-INF/templates/menuAdministrador.xhtml"></ui:decorate>
        </ui:define>

        <ui:define name="content">
            <ui:decorate template="/nuevoProyectoTemplate2.xhtml"></ui:decorate>

        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</html>
```

I've written all the HTML code inside /nuevoProyectoTemplate2 and it works.